# Google Sheets: Add 200 to new rows "after" number format change

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm continually adding new rows to Google Sheets with numerical values in Column C. I need a script (not a formula!) to do 2 things with those numbers.

1. Change the number format to remove commas from any numbers
2. Add 200 to each number

I've got the script for part 1...

```
function setFormat(){SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C2:C").setNumberFormat('##########0');}
```

But I need help with part 2.

Both scripts need to occur immediately upon creation of the number in Column C.

I can't use formulas for these changes. I need to use scripts.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can write whole code within onEdit() function

like this:

```
function onEdit(e){  
  var range = e.range;
  if(range.getColumn() == 3){  //Column C is 3rd column
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C2:C").setNumberFormat('##########0');
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var  r = e.source.getActiveRange();
    var cell = r.getA1Notation();
    var tempval = sheet.getRange(cell).getValue();
    var numval = parseFloat(tempval)+200;
    sheet.getRange(cell).setValue(numval);
  }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks so much @YNK. I'm a total amateur at coding. But I'm trying.

Your answer helps "part" of my question. I'll use "onEdit" at the start of my script to format the number... is this right?...

    function onEdit(e) setFormat(){SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C2:C").setNumberFormat('##########0');}

But I STILL need the script for part 2 of my question... Add 200 to each formatted number. Do you have the script for that as well? Thanks!

Comment: WC @NTC , would you please elaborate what you want In 2nd part ?

Comment: Sure...
Function 1: remove commas from all numbers in Column C...
Function 2: add 200 to all numbers in Column C...

So if the data in the first 3 rows of Column C read:
3,000
4,300
1,800

...then function 1 would render them...
3000
4300
1800

...and function 2 would render them...
3200
4500
2000
...Make sense?

Comment: so close!! Only 1 problem... I only want to add 200 to the "newly edited row"... Currently this script is adding 200 to ALL rows, including the "newly edited row". Can you edit the script 1 more time for me? Much appreciated!!!

Comment: I also get an error on line 2 of the code... "TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 2, file "Code")"

Comment: Actually, after further review, it does NOT remove the comma from the number :(. So we do have a few problems. I appreciate any help you can offer me. Thanks!

Comment: I was able to remove the comma by adding this script: 
    function setFormat(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C2:C").setNumberFormat('##########0');
}

Comment: @NTC Ok , Please check edited code again, i put your line to remove comma and change code to add 200 only for edited cell within C column.

Comment: '@YNK... PERFECT. Wow, thank you so much! I am so grateful for your patience with me and all your help. Thank you!! Any way I can donate to you?

Comment: this one works fine, but I still get an error on line 2 of the code... "TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 2, file "Code")" ... can this be fixed? Thanks!

Comment: If you are running the code from inside the script editor, you will get a range error. In the case of a simple onEdit() trigger, you can only test the code by actually editing a cell. The e event variable will not have anything assigned to it unless you actually edit a cell. I don't get any range errors, if I trigger it by editing a cell.

Comment: Thanks @YNK ! Gimme your PayPal address or something. I need to donate to you :). And I may have a few more questions too :)

Comment: i upvoted... but how do I mark the question as accepted? i can't find that button anywhere?

Comment: @NTC Thanks, You can accept answer by clicking 'tick-mark' below down voting button.. and for more, I can be reached anytime via Skype, my ID is 'yatinkaria' or via email at yatin.karia@gmail.com